# What's difference between Alert Logic Network IDS and AWS Guard Duty?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, logic, alert, intrusion-detection

I was wondering what the core differences were between Alert Logic's dedicated IDS solution and AWS Guard Duty.

I know Alert Logic offer Cloud Insight Essentials that bolt onto Guard Duty, but are AlertLogic IDS and AWS Guard Duty similar?

Do they both offer the same/similar security offerings?
- DNS Query Log analysis
- Ingress, egress and lateral network traffic analysis
- Brute Force, privilege escalation etc.

Thanks!